# problems with facebook cache of my web in the debugger

Tags: php, wordpress, meta, facebook-opengraph

The meta atributes of Open Graph are not working and the debugger is not working well.

I think that the old web is cached. But i can't clean de cache.

Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
Web: http://stereozona.com

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook debugger never uses the cache. It always does a forced scrape.

Do you have an og:url pointing to the wrong page?

Comment: No, the og:url was given by get_permalink function. As you can see in the view-code functionality of the browser.

Comment: @Paul are you FB employee? I think this isn't true, sometimes I get cached result from linter

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is wrong.  If you are changing the og tags you need to "lint" the page by pasting the address into the facebook linter before you re-check.  Eventually (I think a few hours) it will re-scrape your page without doing that, not helpful if testing.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.squidfist.com%2Fdirector-gallery%3Fimg%3D7